# Window size in GLSL for OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a rectangle drawn in my window, and I'd like to color the top half of it a different color (say blue), without hard-coding the height of the pixels.

With a window height of 1000, in my fragment shader, I have:

```
void main(){
if((gl_FragCoord.y) > 500)
{
    color = vec3(.3, .3, 1);
}
else
{
    color = fragmentColor;
}
```

Which colors the top half of the rectangle blue. But what if I'd like to get the window height from inside my fragment shader instead of just using 500 pixels? I initialized
`uniform vec2 windowSize`, and am trying to use `glUniform1i()` to place the window height in this variable, but I don't know how.

Comment: You need to use `glUniform2f` to set the `windowSize` because it's a `vec2`.

Comment: How could I make the call in my fragment shader? Is it glUniform2f(windowSize, ?, ?)? How should I pass in the other two arguments?

Comment: You first obtain a "handle" to the uniform variable via [`glGetUniformLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glGetUniformLocation.xhtml), and then use that "handle" as the first argument for `glUniform2f`. The second and third arguments for `glUniform2f` can be whatever you want.

Comment: @3PA: You don't make the call in the fragment shader. The fragment shader is executed long after any chance to set uniforms has passed. You make the call of `glUniform` in the hosts programs display/drawing routine.

Answer (score 1):

The situation you describe just begs for an `out float` variable in the vertex shader that is set to the current Y coordinate of the rectangle, which, along with the X coordinate and whatever else vertex attributes you have, is passed to your shader by OpenGL.

When it arrives at the fragment shader (the type being `in float`), it gets interpolated, most probably in `[–1; 1]` bounds. So, to paint the upper half blue, you just need to check if that variable is positive.

**N.B.:** if you use GLSL prior to 3.x, `out float VARIABLE_NAME` and `in float VARIABLE_NAME` must both be `varying float VARIABLE_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Uniforms.

```c
uniform float windowWidth;
```

You can learn more [here](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Shaders).