# GLSL How to make input channel in the center of screen, whatever screen size is

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm trying to make the input channel **(London picture)** in the center of the screen, the issue here is I don't want to change **0.5** to make the picture in the center, because if the screen changed, I need to set a new  value once again.

[image]

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
     vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy;
     vec2 q = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
     vec3 camera_video = texture( iChannel0, q ).xyz;

     vec2 pos = vec2(0.5,0.5);
     
     float scale = 1.5;
     
     if (uv.x > pos.x && uv.y > pos.y && uv.x < pos.x + 1./scale && uv.y < pos.y + 1./scale){
        uv -= pos;
        uv *= scale;
        fragColor = texture(iChannel1, uv);
        return;
     }
     
     fragColor = vec4(camera_video, 1.0 );

}
```

**My Question :**

How I can calculate the correct position **x** and **y** to make the picture in the center whatever screen is.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not [tag:c]. This is a [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/) glsl shader.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607668/window-size-in-glsl-for-opengl
It contains info how to pass the window size to the glsl fragment shader. From the window size you can easily determine where to draw your image.

Comment: @Rabbid76 my apologies, it was a mistake

Comment: @wohlstad thank you so much for your help I will check it out

Comment: @wohlstad in fact, I'm working on an Android application, so the screen size is in my hand, how I can befine from it to make the picture in the center?

Answer (score 1):

The screen and texture co-ordinates in GLSL don't change with the size of the image: they always range from -1 to +1 (for the screen) and 0 to 1 (for textures). So 0.5 is always correct for an image 1 unit wide and 1 unit high.

But if you want to account for different aspect ratios of the texture, one way to do that is to use [textureSize()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/textureSize.xhtml) to find out the dimensions of the texture.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I'm a very beginner at the GLSL, the issue here is 0.5 does not center the image on the screen without talking about the different aspect ratios,  that's what makes me confused